# Dynamic number of columns in a Word table using Velocity and XDocReport

Tags: ms-word, velocity, xdocreport

XDocReport and Velocity can be used to create a dynamic number of rows in a Word table, using the foreach loop.  (The before-row and after-row tokens make this even more powerful.)  But the number of columns must be fixed.

But sometimes I don't know the number of columns I will need until the data is added to the template.  Is there any way to dynamically set the number of columns?  If this was HTML, I could likely easily do this (just by looping through the number of columns and adding another TD or TH element to each row), but I can't figure out how to do this in Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a sample with dynamic column in *DocxTableWithoutFieldsMetadataWithVelocity.docx* in the *docxandvelocity-xxx-sample.zip* that you can [download](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/downloads/list) or [in git](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/source/browse/?repo=samples#git%2Fsamples%2Ffr.opensagres.xdocreport.samples.docxandvelocity%2Fsrc%2Ffr%2Fopensagres%2Fxdocreport%2Fsamples%2Fdocxandvelocity%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

The basic idea is to use **@before-cell/@after-cell** :

[image]

Manage loop for column with HTML and docx is the same thing. You could unzip your docx, edit word/document.xml and add at hand the Velocity code to manage loop for column.

But it's not very user friendly, that's why XDocReport preprocess the docx to update word/document.xml with Velocity code by using @before-cell/@after-cell written in a mergefield.

Comment: @Angelo I'm trying to apply your solution but I couldn't make it work. Can you provide a template file as an example?